# How to correct relative addressing after memory copy function to user space?

Tags: c, gcc, operating-system

Hi I'm trying to jump from kernel level to user level using "sysexit", and prepared the following user function:

```
void user_level_function(void)
{
    color_printk(RED, BLACK, "user_level_function task is running\n");
    while(1);
}
```

However GCC compiled as following:

```
ffff80000010322f <user_level_function>:
ffff80000010322f:   55                      push   %rbp
ffff800000103230:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
ffff800000103233:   41 57                   push   %r15
ffff800000103235:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
ffff800000103239:   48 8d 0d f9 ff ff ff    lea    -0x7(%rip),%rcx        # ffff800000103239 <user_level_function+0xa>
ffff800000103240:   49 bb af d9 00 00 00    movabs $0xd9af,%r11
ffff800000103247:   00 00 00 
ffff80000010324a:   4c 01 d9                add    %r11,%rcx
ffff80000010324d:   48 b8 a0 01 00 00 00    movabs $0x1a0,%rax
ffff800000103254:   00 00 00 
ffff800000103257:   48 8d 14 01             lea    (%rcx,%rax,1),%rdx
ffff80000010325b:   be 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%esi
ffff800000103260:   bf 00 00 ff 00          mov    $0xff0000,%edi
ffff800000103265:   49 89 cf                mov    %rcx,%r15
ffff800000103268:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
ffff80000010326d:   49 b8 ca 4a ff ff ff    movabs $0xffffffffffff4aca,%r8
ffff800000103274:   ff ff ff 
ffff800000103277:   49 01 c8                add    %rcx,%r8
ffff80000010327a:   41 ff d0                callq  *%r8
ffff80000010327d:   eb fe                   jmp    ffff80000010327d <user_level_function+0x4e>
```

Above assembly code shows that the function is addressing using its current compiled address.

Therefore after I memory copy the function to user space (0x800000) and execute it, the addressing is disordered due to the relative addressing.

```
unsigned long do_execve(void)
{
    color_printk(RED,BLACK,"do_execve task is running\n");
    memcpy(user_level_function,(void *)0x800000,1024);
    PUSH_ALL;
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "wrmsr  \n\t"
        "movq $0x800000, %%rdx \n\t"
        "movq $0xa00000, %%rcx \n\t"
        ".byte  0x48    \n\t"
        "sysexit        \n\t"
        :
        :"d"((unsigned long)KERNEL_CS >> 32),
         "a"((unsigned long)KERNEL_CS & 0xffffffff),
         "c"(0x174)
        :"memory"
    );
    POP_ALL;
    return 0;
}
```

Therefore I would like to ask if there is a way to solve it?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: 1) How do you compile `user_level_function`?
2) How do you expect to bind the calling code to the address of `color_printk`, anyway? You are not loading this as a kernel module, are you?
3) I think, you got `memcpy` arguments in the wrong order.

Comment: Hi @VladislavIvanishin 1)gcc  -mcmodel=large -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -m64 -c ./OSFiles/Codes/Task.c <==== This is the make file, 3) memcpy I actually re-write it since its self made kernel. 2) Since the compiler will use the relative address, so if I memcpy it to the target address, it will search the address related to the target address. There is an easy way of solving this is simply link the function in front part of the kernel and copy the whole kernel. Otherwise, it may adjust the compiler to search the absolute address instead. For example, using "movq $0xXXX,%rdx"

Comment: Assuming that you're on Linux: Have you checked if maybe [ASLR](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Space_Layout_Randomization) is hampering you? Setting `/proc/sys/vm/randomize_va_space` to `0` may help here (note that you'll be disabling an important security feature here). Note that gdb by default disables ASLR when debugging executables, so the behavior may appear different when debugging the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May the `-fno-pic` compiler option be what you want?